# Bootstrap Stateful Button on a Input Form Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to use the Stateful functionality of a button in a form's submit button (input). But I can not for the life of me figure out how to accomplish that.

My form executes a php page. I want the button to change during the loading of that php page (depending on content, it could take up to 20 seconds). Is this possible?

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons

Sample Code:

```
<form method='post'>
<input type='text' name='test'></input>
<input type='submit' id='loading-example-btn' value='Submit' data-loading-text="Loading...">
</form>
<script>
  $('#loading-example-btn').click(function () {
    var btn = $(this)
    btn.button('loading')
    $.ajax(...).always(function () {
      btn.button('reset')
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Your ajax call is empty. The intended use of this is for example a "load more" button on a webpage. When the button is clicked it sends an ajax call to get more results, and while this is happening the button is disabled.

Comment: My form executes a php page. I want the button to change during the loading of that php page (depending on content, it could take up to 20 seconds). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked for errors in your browser javascript console? As it stands your js is invalid (unless you've abbreviated it?).

Assuming you are not trying to post your form using ajax, just remove the following lines and you should get the behaviour you want:

```
$.ajax(...).always(function () {
  btn.button('reset')
});
```

Additionally, this line is invalid HTML as `input` is a void element and doesn't require the closing `</input>` tag.

```
<input type='text' name='test'></input>
```

Comment: So my lack of understanding of AJAX may be the downfall here. Right now my form submits to a php page and just hangs until the php page is done doing it's thing (curl requests to an API and grabbing results). I have no problem with it hanging, I just want the submit button text to change (or a modal to pop up) during this loading phase.

Comment: Also I have a full form, but it has a little PII so I just made a test form for an example.

Comment: So removing the lines I suggested didn't achieve that? It should work.. http://www.bootply.com/128762

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, that worked for me. Thank you!

Comment: Is there anyway for it to change to Loading... for .5 seconds and then  to Other Text... for the remainder of the time all in the same AJAX call?

Comment: You can only do that if you are using ajax to submit the form, which I'm not sure if you are doing? If you are then you can do something like this: http://www.bootply.com/129005 (note the `data-continue-text` that defines the text to display after 1s)

Comment: Actually that works for me, except the continue text isn't unclickable like loading text is. I'm assuming that's just a CSS thing though.

Comment: Attempting to add `btn.addClass('disabled')` after `btn.button('continue')` does not actually add the class. Any tip here? I can't find anything on the internet about button('continue') nor can I find this function in the bootstrap js.

Comment: Since this is a new question, I added it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994789/bootstrap-jquery-loading-state-auto-disables-button-how-to-get-other-states-to