# Bootstrap JQuery loading state auto disables button, how to get other states to do the same

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

`$this.button('loading')` auto adds `disabled` class to it while it's running, I want to create a second version of `$this.button('loading')`. So I can have 2 versions of text in a loading button.

If I use a custom entry such as `continue` or `loading2`, it applies the text but does not apply the `disabled` class during that timeframe

Example

http://www.bootply.com/129005#

I've tried just doing an attr add and changing the html of the button, which works. But the form actually won't ever complete, it just hangs on the second text.

The second portion of text needs to stay until the php page it calls gets completed (which works fine right now with the example above, besides the button is clickable during the `continue` portion.

Comment: So, if i understand correct, your problem is that button is't disabled during loading?

Comment: It's disabled during loading, but not during the second loading status

Comment: @pero Perfect!!!!!! mark it as an answer and I'll vote it up.

Comment: @AndrewWilson thanks, but my mistake on the first example! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the bootstrap [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons), the second invocation of `btn.button(...)` after the timeout will reset the button state:

> **$().button(string)**
>
> Resets button state - swaps text to any data defined text state.

Instead you just want to modify the text of the button in it's existing state, i.e:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    btn.prop('value', 'still going..')  
}, 1000);
```

http://www.bootply.com/129028